# Parceler unwrap giving wrong data

Tags: android, parcelable, parcel, parceler

I'm using [parceler](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler) library to implement Parcelable interface.

I have such model

```
@Parcel(Parcel.Serialization.BEAN)
public class Ads {
private Long id;
private String title;
private String description;
private AdsType adsType;
private String phone;
private String email;
private String city;
private Long categoryId;
private ArrayList<Integer> creationDate;
//TODO remove transient
private transient ArrayList<Long> imageIds;
private transient Long price;


@SerializedName("adsCategory")
private AdvCategory advCategory;

public Ads() {}

public Ads(String title, String description, AdsType adsType, String
        phone, String email, String city, Long categoryId, Long price, ArrayList<Long> imageIds) {
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.adsType = adsType;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.email = email;
    this.city = city;
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
    this.price = price;
    this.imageIds = imageIds;
}

@ParcelConstructor
public Ads(Long id, String title, String description, AdsType adsType,
           String phone, String email, String city, ArrayList<Long>
                   imageIds, Long price, ArrayList<Integer> creationDate, AdvCategory advCategory) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.adsType = adsType;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.email = email;
    this.city = city;
    this.imageIds = imageIds;
    this.price = price;
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
    this.advCategory = advCategory;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public AdsType getAdsType() {
    return adsType;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public AdvCategory getAdvCategory() {
    return advCategory;
}

public void setAdvCategory(AdvCategory advCategory) {
    this.advCategory = advCategory;
}

public Long getCategoryId() {
    return categoryId;
}

public ArrayList<Long> getImageIds() {
    return imageIds;
}

public void setImageIds(ArrayList<Long> imageIds) {
    this.imageIds = imageIds;
}

public int getPrice() {
    //TODO replace with real price
    return new Random().nextInt(100000);
}

public void setPrice(Long price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}

public void setCreationDate(ArrayList<Integer> creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Ads ads = (Ads) o;
    return id.equals(ads.id);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = id.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + title.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + description.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + adsType.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + (phone != null ? phone.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (email != null ? email.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (city != null ? city.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + advCategory.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + (categoryId != null ? categoryId.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Ads{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", title='" + title + '\'' +
            ", description='" + description + '\'' +
            ", adsType=" + adsType +
            ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", city='" + city + '\'' +
            ", creationDate='" + creationDate.toString() +
            '}';
}

public static class List extends ArrayList<Ads> {}
}
```

I'm wraping my model and puting it into intent.

```
 Intent adsDetailsIntent = new Intent(this, AdsDetailsActivity.class);
    Bundle details = new Bundle();
    Ads advertisement = mAdsAdapter.getItem(position);
    details.putParcelable(AdsDetailsActivity.ADS_DETAILS, Parcels.wrap(advertisement));
    Ads ads = Parcels.unwrap(details.getParcelable(AdsDetailsActivity.ADS_DETAILS));
    Log.d("ads", ads.toString());
    adsDetailsIntent.putExtras(details);
    startActivity(adsDetailsIntent);
```

And unwrapping in activity

```
mAdsDetails = Parcels.unwrap(
            (Parcelable) this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra(ADS_DETAILS));
```

but sometimes field "creationDate" has wrong value after unwrapping in activity.

I tried to log it, and after unwrapping from Bundle - it's ok, but in activity - it has weird data.

Example :

> unwrap from bundle immediately after creating it
>
> Ads{id=16, title='Mtitle', description='Mads', adsType=BUY, phone='+30890931231', email='+380932309046', city='Анабарский национальный улус', creationDate='[2015, 8, 8, 9, 27, 0, 350946000]}
>
> unwrap from activity intent.getExtra()
>
> Ads{id=null, title='null', description='null', adsType=null, phone='null', email='null', city='null', creationDate='[8, 8, 9, 27, 0, 350946000, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,

I don't know why, but it's creating an array with creationDate[1](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler) size and filling it with zeros.

Comment: In your example you are logging the contents of the Bundle details without marshalling the Bundle to the AdsDetailsActivity.  Can you log the results of unwrapping the ADS_DETAILS Parcelable in the onCreate() method of AdsDetailsActivity?

Comment: @JohnEricksen - I believe I have boiled this down to a mismatch between serialization format and deserialization format - see below and linked bug made for Parceler

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in your unwrapping the class

```
mAdsDetails = Parcels.unwrap(
            (Parcelable) this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra(ADS_DETAILS));
```

Have you tried it this way:

```
mAdsDetails = Parcels.unwrap(this.getIntent().getExtras().get(ADS_DETAILS));
```

Comment: I tried, same thing. I'm not getting nullpointer when getting data, I'm getting wrong data.

Comment: I doubt this is the issue... although the cast to Parcelable is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be related to the discrepancy between the `int` return type of the `#getPrice` function and the `Long` type of the `price` argument to the constructor annotated with `@ParcelConstructor`.

This will result in generated code that:

1. writes an integer into the parcel for serialization
2. attempts to read a complex, larger type upon deserialization
3. deserialization continues, but effectively reading garbage since the `readFoo` methods are called with the "wrong" offset in the buffer

Specifically, when inspecting the code generated by Parceler and debugging the same issue in my code I found that:

- primitive types are written directly into the parcel as a single value
- complex types (like the wrappers for primitive types) are written with *two* values: one for `null` vs. non-`null` as a flag, and then possibly the actual value if not `null`

See this issue I made for the Parceler project:

https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler/issues/234